# In my django app, how to show all posts of similar category if that category is selected?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, web-deployment

I'm new to Django so bear with me please.

I'm creating an app for posting jobs, and it's based on Corey Schafer's [social media tutorial](https://youtu.be/UmljXZIypDc).

Each post/job in my app has a category field (NGO, Engineering, Oil&Gas, etc...) My goal is if I select a category, then all jobs of the same category are listed. Corey did the same with the "all posts of a selected author " approach, but I couldn't do similar thing with my category goal.
 I appreciate all help for guidance.
If the pics aren't enough, a general guidance is fine, thanks!

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXUo3.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsZuN.png)

[model.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpKvJ.png)

Comment: What have you tried, specifically, that's similar to the "all posts of a selected author" approach? I would replicate the view and url from that approach almost exactly.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, it's far easier for user to help you when you post your code in the question

Comment: I think it's "best practice" or maybe proper etiquette to paste and format your code here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone, and apologize for the late reply. I've found my answer to be related to the answer given below by Shantanu Nath.

Answer (score 0):

Fawaz where are your views for "CategoryPostAutoListView"
if u want posts with the selected category, u can filter with the selected category in your views. such as

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(category = selected category)
```

if u don't understand please clear me in detail about your problem.

Comment: Yes your suggestion was key to the answer I was looking for; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After hard digging, I found what I was looking for

```
 def all_category_jobs(request, category_name, **kwargs):

      obj = Postauto.objects.filter(category = category_name)

      template_name='myapp/targetpage.html'

      context = {"catagory_list":obj}

      return render(request, template_name, context,)
```